# get location of tray icon from windows registry

Tags: windows, registry, trayicon

How do I get the coordinates of a particular tray icon from the windows registry?

For instance, dropbox has a tray icon, how would I get the position of that icon?

Comment: You can't. It's not stored in the registry.

Comment: So is there a way to get the location of a tray icon?